# Convert YoloV8 to Tflite

Tags: machine-learning, bounding-box, yolov5, tflite

I have trained a custom model using Yolov8. I want to implement this model in my flutter app through the "google_mlkit_object_detection: ^0.6.0" package, for that I must convert it to tflite. But when I run

```
!yolo export model=best.pt format=tflite
```

I get "NotImplementedError: YOLOv8 TensorFlow export support is still under development."

But I have seen posts like the one bellow, of people who managed to convert

[Interpreting YOLOv8->TFlite output](https://discuss.roboflow.com/t/interpreting-yolov8-tflite-output/1562)

I can convert to onnx though, is it easier to convert from onnx to tflite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have an old version of the `ultralytics` package. Update it by:

```
pip install --upgrade ultralytics
```

and try again. TFLite exports are available in `master` as can be seen here: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/4198570a4ba98351107527142d85125eb8d0039f/ultralytics/yolo/engine/exporter.py#L504-L548